# Filter list based on multiple classes u

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filtering

I'm trying to `.show()` or `.hide()` certain `li` elements based on multiple classes that are selected out of an array.

Here is an example of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="category-list">
  <ul class="light" id="category-menu">
    <li id="client-x"><a class="work-item" onclick="toggleContent('client-x')">Client X</a></li>
    <li id="client-y"><a class="work-item" onclick="toggleContent('client-y')">Client Y</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the function that I'm calling:

```
function toggleContent(id) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var ez = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    var cats = [];    
    var items = window.localStorage.getItem('items');

if (items === null || items.length === 0) {  
    cats.push(id);
    $(".port-project").hide(); 
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(cats));
    $(ez).closest(".port-project").show();
} else {
    cats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));       
            if (cats.indexOf(id) > -1) {
                for(var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++){                       
                    if (cats[i] === id){
                    cats.splice(i, 1);
                    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(cats));
                    //$(ez).closest(".port-project").hide();
                    }   
                }           
            } else {                
                cats.push(id);
                localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(cats));
                //$(ez).closest(".port-project").show();
            }   
    }
$(".port-project").filter(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))).show();
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is store of group of classes in an array which is then stored in `localStroage`. From there when someone clicks on on a filter I want to show or hide `.port-projects` based on the items that are stored in the localStorage, but only display the projects that **include all items** in that array (which is accessed through `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify`). The second if/else is only adding or removing classes based on whether the class is already present or not.

I've read through countless threads and I'm trying to use the `.filter` feature to check the localStorage but I think I've mucked up the process. Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance from this newbie.

Comment: Do you really need doc ready inside of your `toggleContent` function?

Comment: It's a Wordpress site. In order to use JQuery it's my understanding you need to wrap the script in this. Otherwise it won't work properly. May be right or wrong, but this way works so far and removing it causes nothing to fire.